# What does Statis mode not supported mean in ShinyApps?

Tags: shiny, shinyapps

I keep on receiving this error when trying to deploy my app to a shinyapps.io.  What is this error and what should I do? Error: Unhandled Exception Application mode static not supported.

I tried restarting a new R shiny app and renaming the app.R file, but it did not work.